# Is there a copyable function wrapper in C++23 with support for const/ref/noexcept?

Tags: c++, c++23

C++23 introduces [`std::move_only_function`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/move_only_function) which has support for `const` and `l/r-value-reference` on the implicit `this` parameter and `noexcept(true/false)` on the function itself.

The old [`std::function`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/function) is lacking these overloads.

```cpp
#include <functional>

int main(){
    std::function<void()>([]noexcept(true){});          // okay ✓
    std::function<void()>([]noexcept(false){});         // okay ✓
    std::function<void()noexcept>([]noexcept(true){});  // not supported
    std::function<void()noexcept>([]noexcept(false){}); // not supported

    std::move_only_function<void()>([]noexcept(true){});          // okay ✓
    std::move_only_function<void()>([]noexcept(false){});         // okay ✓
    std::move_only_function<void()noexcept>([]noexcept(true){});  // okay ✓
    std::move_only_function<void()noexcept>([]noexcept(false){}); // fails ✓

    std::function<void()>([i=0]{});             // okay ✓
    std::function<void()>([i=0]mutable{});      // okay ✓
    std::function<void()const>([i=0]{});        // not supported
    std::function<void()const>([i=0]mutable{}); // not supported

    std::move_only_function<void()>([i=0]{});             // okay ✓
    std::move_only_function<void()>([i=0]mutable{});      // okay ✓
    std::move_only_function<void()const>([i=0]{});        // okay ✓
    std::move_only_function<void()const>([i=0]mutable{}); // fails ✓
}
```

Unfortunately, as the name suggests, `std::move_only_function` cannot be copied.

```cpp
#include <functional>
#include <vector>

int main(){
    auto const fn = []{};

    std::function<void()> a = fn;
    std::vector<std::function<void()>> a_list{a, a};

    std::move_only_function<void()> b = fn;
    std::vector<std::move_only_function<void()>> b_list{b, b}; // error
}
```

Is there an analog function wrapper that supports copying? If this is not the case in C++23, is there a library that provides this?

I need a data type that is the owner of the function.

Comment: What? I am confused. Use `std::function` if the callable can be copied. Use `std::move_only_function` in case it is move-only. Can you give a proper example of what you are lacking and why?

Comment: @ALX23z I have added source code examples to clarify the problems.

Comment: Then just use the `std::function`. The additional `cv-ref-noexcept` qualifiers are unnecessary in `std::function` for the most part. You still haven't clarified why you need the function qualifiers, it seems unnecessary to me.

Comment: @ALX23z Because I want to call the function wrapper object from a noexcept function of course. This function reads the callbacks from a queue and all callbacks are required to not throw any exceptions. With move_only_function I can make it a compile time error if a user tries to add a non-noexcept function to the queue, with std::function I need to trust the user to do the right thing as documented.

Comment: Do you realize that copying a `std::function` may throw an exception? How exactly requiring that the `operator ()` is `noexcept` is helpful here?

Comment: @ALX23z The copying happens in the part that sets up the queue. This is not a problem. The user can catch the exception in this case normally and decide for himself how he wants to react to it.

Comment: now I am confused. Why do you even need the copying for then? Just the `std::move_only_function`.

Comment: To me it looks like you have an XY problem. You are asking the wrong question here. You don't need copying on your side, and I don't see any reason why copying would be needed on the user's side of the queue either. You'd better fix whatever mess happens on user's side so copying isn't needed. Also, I habe serious doubts that requiring user to supply `noexcept` callables would help. They'll just end up marking functions `noexcept` regardless of possible exceptions, and perhaps file a bunch of bug reports for noreason just because code doesn't compile.

Comment: @ALX23z I am not allowed or able to show you our code here. But the accepted answer shows that what I am looking for is currently standardized. I think that is proof enough that the use case exists and is also not uncommon. ;-)

Comment: the papper only shows that some people wants it standardized, but it doesn't mean that it will ever be. The document lacks motivation/usecase for the addition besides uniformity with `std::move_only_function` which is introduced in C++23...

Comment: @ALX23z I added additional examples regarding const instead of noexcept. Maybe this is simpler to understand …

Comment: *facepalm* you fail to provide usecase. Not every random combination of letters needs to have a meaning, nor every template class needs to support all edge cases that nobody needs. What you have is an XY problem https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem

Comment: @ALX23z I solved my issue with the provided solution. No further need for discussion.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Is there an analog function wrapper that supports copying? If this is not the case in C++23, is there a library that provides this?

No.

In C++26 there will be `std::copyable_function` ([P2548](https://wg21.link/p2548)). There is a [reference implementation](https://github.com/MFHava/P2548).